# Admob ads suddenly stopped showing up in apps

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

I just built my own app using Unity and placed ads on it. It showed up properly for a few days but now suddenly stopped. The app is **unpublished** and most of the impressions are from my own device (around 1500). The number of requests show up correctly on the Admob console but the number of impressions is 0 and the match rate is also 0%. There is nothing on my Admob console suggesting that my account is disabled or any of the ids have expired. Test ads still work fine and it has been so for the last 3-4 days (tested across multiple devices). Any help would be appreciated

```
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
AdManager.bannerAd = new BannerView(adID, GetBanner(), AdPosition.Top);
AdManager.bannerAd.LoadAd(request);
```

Comment: I face the same conflict and i seen that https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-help-forum/8oc3pebOrFw;context-place=forum/google-admob-help-forum , Is it common issue in around the world wide please check it

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what happened. Still hasn't resolved. Let me know if you find a solution.

Comment: Admob team doesn't respond  and still not working , did you get any solution?

Comment: No solution yet. I don't know if I should publish my app yet or wait for ads to reappear

Comment: now its working , please check your app

Comment: It isn't working for me yet. Did you have to change anything in your code or settings?

Comment: No, check again

Comment: Have a match rate of 5.78% today :(

Comment: I have the same issue in last 2 days. How about you? What can I do?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know any particular solution. It just fixed itself after a few days